# Spring security, why do I keep getting logged in automatically?

Tags: java, spring, angular

I followed this tutorial to combine Angular and Spring security:

[Spring Security and Angular](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_the_login_page_angular_js_and_spring_security_part_ii)

I can copy/paste the code here, but basically it has an app.component.html that displays one or another router-outlet depending on whether we are logged in or not.

If you are logged in, the component displayed shows a resource loaded from localhost:8080/resource, but if you are not, it shows the login form component. All works fine. I go to localhost:8080/home and it displays the login form. Once logged in, it displays the resource, when logged out, it displays the login form again.

My problem is that, with a new browser that has all cookies cleaned, I still can access localhost:8080/resoure. Even worse, after that, if I go later to localhost:8080/home it displays the component with the /resource as if I had logged in. It is like if the authentication was totally skipped even the configure of the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter prevents accessing any resource without being authenticated:

```
  http.httpBasic()
  .and()
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/index.html", "/", "/home", "/login").permitAll()
  .anyRequest().authenticated()
  .and()
  .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
```

So my question is, what is failing here? Why I can access localhost:8080/resource even I am not authenticated?

**Edit, Tested with incognito as proposed in a comment:**

With the incognito, same thing happens. Only the very first time I cannot access http://localhost:8080/resource. After that no matter how many times i logout or restart browser, I still can access it. Only after I clean the whole history+cache+cookies I lose access to /resource. According to the tutorial:

> If the user is authenticated then we show a "logout" link and hook it
>   to a logout() function in the AppComponent. Remember, it sends an HTTP
>   POST to "/logout" which we now need to implement on the server. This
>   is straightforward because it is added for us already by Spring
>   Security (i.e. we don’t need to do anything for this simple use case).

Reading this I would expect that the POST logout, which I see is sent from the browser, clears any authentication for this session... is this correct?

Comment: Have you tried in incognito-mode? Basic auth is not dependent on cookies, so make sure that your browser is not caching the credentials.

Comment: If it is not using a cookie... then is it sending each time the user and password to authenticate any request?

Comment: Yes, basic auth works that way. The browser will cache it till end-of-session (i.e. closing the browser)

Comment: @MortenHaraldsen how can we avoid it . I am using the  PostMan   still facing this issue.